# Hide/remove null attributes in Mapbox GL JS popups created via table

Tags: javascript, html-table, popup, mapbox-gl-js

I created a Mapbox map where you can click on points to open popups. The information that is displayed in the popups is stored in a table. There are some null fields with no information though. If that is the case, I would like the whole row to disappear from the popup, including the header of the row.

Here is the code I am using. If the "Information" field in the table is null, the popup is supposed to show just the name of the city, not more (not even the header saying "Information"). How can you achieve that?

```
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: [0, -15]})
.setMaxWidth("auto")
.setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
.setHTML(
`<table>\
                <tr>\
                  <td>City Name</td>\
                  <td>${feature.properties.City}</td>
                </tr>\
                <tr>\
                  <td>Information</td>\
                  <td><${feature.properties.Information}</td>
                </tr>\</table>`) .addTo(map);});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`map.on('click', ['contour-1', 'contour-2', 'contour-3'], (e) => {
   const feature = e.features[0];
   data = feature.properties;
   var table = "<table>";
   for (let key in data) {
      table += `<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${data[key]}</td></tr>`;
   }
   table += "</table>";
   new mapboxgl.Popup()
   .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
   .setHTML(
   '<div>'
      + table
      + 'Координаты: ' + Number((e.lngLat.lng).toFixed(6)) + ', ' + Number((e.lngLat.lat).toFixed(6)) +
   '</div>'
   )
   .addTo(map);
});`
```

The datasource for the mvt tiles is Django models.JSONField.
No need to configure NUll, length can be variable

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with Mapbox here. There are lots of ways to accomplish this. Typically you construct the HTML in pieces like this:

```
let html = `<table>`;
if (feature.properties.City) {
    html += `<tr>
                  <td>City Name</td>
                  <td>${feature.properties.City}</td>
                </tr>`
}
if (feature.properties.Information) {
    html += `<tr>
                  <td>Information</td>
                  <td><${feature.properties.Information}</td>
                </tr>`;
}
html += `</table>`
popup.setHTML(html)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Unfortunatley, due to my poor programming skills, I was not able to integrate your code in my html page - my workaround: I split the table (with null fields) in several tables, of which none has null fields. Little work though...